# Is there any alternative method to send e-mail from my IOS application if the default mail application has not been configured.?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mfmailcomposer

i am asking this question because many of my clients are not using the default mail client. the present code am using in my app is given bellow. I just wanted to know that if it is possible to send mail from any other mail clients.. other than the default mail client.?

```
Class mailClass = (NSClassFromString(@"MFMailComposeViewController"));
if (mailClass != nil)
{
     if ([mailClass canSendMail])
     {
         //Mail composer view is displayed
     }
     else{
         //Error - Mail not configured
     }

}
else
{
    //Error - Mail not configured    
}
```

Comment: you can server-side send mail using web-services